# how to highlight some words in value of input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to hightlight some particular words which are coming dynamically in input tag's value. i want to highlight those words.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <input type='textarea' value="some dynamic value from backend">
</body>
</html>
```

and i want to highlight some words as per my logic of checking that word from input and then highlighting its background.
**Note: text is not a div but it is value of input tag**
i tried doing first grabing that input tag by getElementbyId and then getting its value
then spliting it in an array but when i am accessing a particular element of that array and trying to changle style.background='red';
arr=val.split(' ')
its saying no function style.background please help me! thanks

Comment: **You cannot style parts of an input's value.**

Answer (score -2):

First, you used the wrong way of  tag.

```
<input type='text' value="some dynamic value from backend">
```

In this case it is best to use a WYSIWYG editor like CKEditor, TinyMCE..etc.